# What are strict and non-strict mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have started using moq for mocking. Can someone explain me the concept of strict and non-strict mocks? How can they can be used in moq?

**edit:**
in which scenario do we use which type of mock?

Comment: Was wondering if strict vs non-strict is the same as the difference between  "strict unit tests" and "loose (black-box) unit testing" described in the [angular $httpBackend documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm not sure about moq specifically, but here's how strict mocks work in Rhino.  I declare that I expect a call to `foo.Bar` on my object `foo`:

```
foo.Expect(f => f.Bar()).Returns(5);
```

If the calling code does

```
foo.Bar();
```

then I'm fine because the expectations are exactly met.

However, if the calling code is:

```
foo.Quux(12);
foo.Bar();
```

then my expectation failed because I did not explicitly expect a call to `foo.Quux`.

To summarize, a strict mock will fail immediately if anything differs from the expectations.  On the other hand, a non-strict mock (or a stub) will gladly "ignore" the call to `foo.Quux` and it should return a `default(T)` for the return type `T` of `foo.Quux`.

The creator of Rhino [recommends that you avoid strict mocks](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Mocks+3.5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1#CreateMockisdeprecated,replacedbyStrictMockTheuseofStrictMockisdiscouraged) (and prefer stubs) because you generally don't want your test to fail when receiving an unexpected call as above.  It makes refactoring your code much more difficult when you have to fix dozens of test that relied on the *exact* original behavior.

Comment: where have you specified it is a strict mock?

Comment: @Sandbox:  You would specify strict or non-strict in [the `Mock` constructor that takes a `MockBehavior` argument](http://www.clariusconsulting.net/labs/moq/html/DD4BEE30.htm).  The default behavior (when not specifying the `MockBehavior`) appears to be non-strict (they call it "loose").

Comment: I think it'd be good to include Mark's comment in the answer itself; both the explanation of how to create strict vs non-strict, and a mention of the alias "loose".

Answer (score 4):

Ever come across Given / When / Then?

- Given a context
- When I perform some events
- Then an outcome should occur

This pattern appears in BDD's scenarios, and is also relevant for unit tests.

If you're setting up context, you're going to use the information which that context provides. For instance, if you're looking up something by Id, that's context. If it doesn't exist, the test won't run. In this case, you want to use a NiceMock or a Stub or whatever - Moq's default way of running.

If you want to verify an outcome, you can use Moq's verify. In this case, you want to record the relevant interactions. Fortunately, this is also Moq's default way of running. It won't complain if something happens that you weren't interested in for that test.

StrictMock is there for when you want no unexpected interactions to occur. It's how old-style mocking frameworks used to run. If you're doing BDD-style examples, you probably won't want this. It has a tendency to make tests a bit brittle and harder to read than if you separate the aspects of behaviour you're interested in. You have to set up expectations for both the context and the outcome, for all outcomes which will occur, regardless of whether they're of interest or not.

For instance, if you're testing a controller and mocking out both your validator and your repository, and you want to verify that you've saved your object, with a strict mock you also have to verify that you've validated the object first. I prefer to see those two aspects of behaviour in separate examples, because it makes it easier for me to understand the value and behaviour of the controller.

In the last four years I haven't found a single example which required the use of a strict mock - either it was an outcome I wanted to verify (even if I verify the number of times it's called) or a context for which I can tell if I respond correctly to the information provided. So in answer to your question:

- **non-strict mock:** usually
- **strict mock:** preferably never

NB: I am strongly biased towards BDD, so hard-core TDDers may disagree with me, and it will be right for the way that they are working.

Comment: How do you avoid issues where the method changes functionality and then you don't have any tests validating this new functionality because all your unit tests still pass?

Comment: @DanielLorenz If you're changing functionality you write a failing test first; that's a core part of the TDD cycle regardless of what kind of mock you're using. If you're referring to methods unintentionally changing, having readable tests with responsibilities carefully considered reduces the likelihood of that happening anyway.

Comment: I think the best way to approach this is to have all your tests loose except for one that is strict.  That way, if you make a bunch of changes like that, 1 test will fail and will remind you to make sure you have all your new cases covered, but it won't be such a pain to fix that one test then.

Comment: @DanielLorenz If you're doing TDD right, it hardly ever catches bugs. It does however help with great design and self-commenting code. I find that people who think of it as "testing" tend to pin down their code so it doesn't break; I prefer to make it easy and safe to change. But then I'm really a BDDer, not a TDDer, even at this level. https://dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/

Comment: I'm not really a TDDer either, but if it prevents 1 bug by adding 1 strict test, it was already worth it. :)  If you don't have any strict tests, you might have missed a unit test without realizing it.  I'd rather have peace of mind that at least 1 test is going to catch that for me.

Comment: @DanielLorenz Bear in mind that the purpose of TDD is to make things *easy* to change. If you put very rigid tests in place it will make it harder, not easier, to change the code. I suggest trying both ways. 20+ years of coding has led me to a very strong preference for non-strict mocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good [article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).
I usually end up having something like this

```
public class TestThis {

    private final Collaborator1 collaborator1;
    private final Collaborator2 collaborator2;
    private final Collaborator2 collaborator3;

    TestThis(Collaborator1 collaborator1, Collaborator2 collaborator2, Collaborator3 collaborator3) {
        this.collaborator1 = collaborator1;
        this.collaborator2 = collaborator2;
        this.collaborator3 = collaborator3;
    }

    public Login login(String username) {
        User user = collaborator1.getUser(username);
        collaborator2.notify(user);
        return collaborator3.login(user);
    }

}
```

...and I use Strict mocks for the 3 collaborators to test login(username). I don't see how Strict Mocks should never be used.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple convention:

1. Use strict mocks when the system under test (SUT) is delegating the call to the underlying mocked layer without really modifying or applying any business logic to the arguments passed to itself.
2. Use loose mocks when the SUT applies business logic to the arguments passed to itself and passes on some derived/modified values to the mocked layer.

For eg:
Lets say we have database provider StudentDAL which has two methods:

Data access interface looks something like below:

```
public Student GetStudentById(int id);
public IList<Student> GetStudents(int ageFilter, int classId);
```

The implementation which consumes this DAL looks like below:

```
public Student FindStudent(int id)
{
   //StudentDAL dependency injected
   return StudentDAL.GetStudentById(id);
   //Use strict mock to test this
}
public IList<Student> GetStudentsForClass(StudentListRequest studentListRequest)
{
  //StudentDAL dependency injected
  //age filter is derived from the request and then passed on to the underlying layer
  int ageFilter = DateTime.Now.Year - studentListRequest.DateOfBirthFilter.Year;
  return StudentDAL.GetStudents(ageFilter , studentListRequest.ClassId)
  //Use loose mock and use verify api of MOQ to make sure that the age filter is correctly passed on.

}
```