# types of mocking static vs dynamic

Tags: .net, mocking, moq

I am a beginner in .net framework. Recently, I came to know that there are two types of mocking, Static vs dynamic. Can anyone explain me the differences with examples and also how it can be implemented using Moq framework.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Static Mocks**

I hope you have not confused with [Strict vs Non-Strict mocks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134108/what-are-strict-and-non-strict-mocks)
As far as [Moq](https://github.com/Moq) concern, the Static mocks are irrelvent. 
I think it is more or less inherited from one of the older programming languages and people refer to it as
hand written mocks. Static mocks is the old way you creat mock objects. Which is [handwritten or hardcoded/static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370617/hard-coded-mock-objects-vs-mocking-framework) mocks.

```
internal class MyMockDataSource : IDataSource
{ 
  #region IDataSource Members implementation
  …
  #endregion
}
```

You then inject the MyMockDataSource into your SUT (System Under Test) for verification, or as fake container if it was a Stub (i.e StubDataSource).
**[Stub vs Mock](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)*

However Static Mocks become very tedious as so much repeated code, and it is not easier to maintain this extra code either. It good for simple application, but not good for mid-large applications.

**Dynamic Mocks**

This is where the Dynmaic Mocking has been used. Of course there are plenty of example on how you create dynamic mocks using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart), which I won't go through as you can easily find them on the web.